# Get list from C array from .h file

Tags: python, c

I have C header file, with 16 const unsigned char arrays with the size of 8820 bytes.

```
const unsigned char hex0[8820] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0xCF, 0x00, 0x65, 0x01, 0x15, 0x02,
0xD8, 0x02, 0x9C, 0x03, 0x5C, 0x04, 0x07, 0x05, 0x91, 0x05, 0xF3, 0x05,
... 
}
```

I need to convert this to Python's lists, what is the best way to do that? Is there some tool for that? Or shall I parse it with regular expressions?

Comment: You can totally do `hex0 = [0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, ...` in python. Some simple python code (`readlines`, `re` etc) can convert this string in header file to python code.

Comment: Open the source in some text editor and do the following find/replace alls, "const unsigned char ", with "", "[8820]" with "", "{" with "[" and "}" with "]"

Comment: you can copy-paste it manually....

Comment: Everything except the first & last line is valid Python, so you can easily turn it into a string representing a list, or a list of lists, and parse that string efficiently using `ast.literal_eval`.